# pass data from UIKit to SwiftUI (container UIHostingController)

Tags: swift, swiftui

How to pass data between `UIViewController` and `struct ContentView`?

I tried with `ObservableObject` but I can't get the data up to date.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail about what you are trying to do? Posting the source code (of what you already tried) would definitely help.

Comment: Did you take a look at `updateUIViewController(_:,context:)`?

Comment: my application(UIKit) has a view containing a Container(Swiftui) and I want to pass data from my view(UIViewcontroller) to my Container(UIHostingController).

Comment: You can attach an `environmentObject` to your SwiftUI rootView. I will write an answer explaining how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add `class myclassname: ObservableObject`
2. In the class create a variable with `@Published var myvar` and add:

   ```
   init(myvar: type) {
     self.myvar = myvar
   }
   ```
3. In `UIViewController` add:

   ```
   private var model = myclassname(myvar: XXX)`
   ```

   and in `viewWillAppear` add:

   ```
   let vc = myclassname(myvar: myvar)
   let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView(model: vc))
   ```
4. In the `struct` add:

   ```
   @ObservedObject var model: myclassname
   ```

Comment: This works. It should be noted that if your view accepts a binding $property (for example in your preview you use @State) then $model.property will work in its place, if you follow Yug's steps here.

Answer (score 11):

To pass data from a `UIViewController` to an SwiftUI-Struct inside an `UIHostingController` you can attach an `environmentObject` to the SwiftUI `rootView`:

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: YourContentView().environmentObject(yourEnvironmentObject))
```

Of course you'll need to create an ObservableObject and add it to your SwiftUI-Struct.

Create the ObservableObject:

```
class TypeOfEnvironmentObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data = "myData"
}
```

Add it to your struct:

```
@EnvironmentObject var yourEnvironmentObject: TypeOfEnvironmentObject
```

Comment: Thanks! Guys.  Yeah, I've done that before. But when the data value is updated my structure doesn't take the updates it stays with the initialization value.

Comment: Ok I think I understood what you are trying to do. If I got you right the Combine-Framework is what you're looking for: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/receiving_and_handling_events_with_combine?language=objc

Comment: With Combine you can connect a publisher in your UIViewController with a subscriber in your SwiftUI-Struct. When your data changes you can use the publisher to notify the subscriber.

Comment: I'm trying, but I don't get the concept. Can you give me a little example?

Comment: thank you so much guys for your answers. I've been successful with `ObservableObject` and I'll try to detail if it can help anyone else.

Answer (score 8):

I found the existing answers confusing/incomplete, perhaps something changed around generic inference in Swift 5.3 etc. While you can add an environment object to the UIHostingController's view this seems to conflict with the types (i.e. the generic parameter to UIHostingController needs a concrete type). Adding `AnyView` resolves this:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct TutorialView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var integration: TutorialIntegrationService
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hi").navigationBarTitle("test: \(integration.id)")
    }
}

class TutorialIntegrationService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var id: Int = 0
}

class TutorialViewController: UIHostingController<AnyView> {
    
    let integration = TutorialIntegrationService()
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder,rootView: AnyView(TutorialView().environmentObject(integration)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrapping in `AnyView` seems to not be needed anymore. (observed in February 2024, Xcode 15 and Swift 5.9.2)